# JavaFX OnMouseDragged not getting fired when dragging an Item in a Treeview

Tags: java, drag-and-drop, treeview, javafx-8

Bascially I try to implement the behaviour, that when dragging an item from a treeView and going either at the bottom or top of the treeView, the treeView will automatically scroll down or up.

Thus far I was able to simply extend the TreeView and add a onMouseDragged event handler to it. like this

```
public ExtendedTreeView()
{
    super();

    setOnMouseDragged((MouseEvent event) -> onMouseMoved(event));
}
```

The event handler then looks like this (System outs are bascially just for debug purpose)

```
private void onMouseMoved(MouseEvent event)
{
    System.out.println("onMouseMoved-----------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println(event.getEventType().toString());

    // -----only apply when there is a drag event in progress
    if(event.getEventType().equals(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DRAGGED))
    {
        // -----first check if we are the scrollEdges
        System.out.println(String.format("Size: %f : %f", getWidth(), getHeight()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Bounds: %f : %f : %f : %f", _scrollBounds.getTop(), _scrollBounds.getRight(), _scrollBounds.getBottom(), _scrollBounds.getLeft()));
        System.out.println(String.format("Node: %f : %f", event.getX(), event.getY()));

        //-----up and down directions are preferred
        ScrollDirection direction = ScrollDirection.None;
        if(event.getY() <= _scrollBounds.getTop())
            direction = ScrollDirection.Top;
        else if(event.getY() >= _scrollBounds.getBottom())
            direction = ScrollDirection.Bottom;
        else if(event.getX() >= _scrollBounds.getRight())
            direction = ScrollDirection.Right;
        else if(event.getX() <= _scrollBounds.getLeft())
            direction = ScrollDirection.Left;

        System.out.println(String.format("Direction: %s", direction.toString()));
    }
}
```

When I drag and move the mouse in the TreeView it get the desired result.

The Problem is how ever
as soon as I drag an actuall Item, the drag event only occurs once and then never again.

The Item also has a drag and drop handling which essentially looks like this.
Note that this is actually a controller which has info about which TreeCell he belongs to.

```
@FXML
public void onDragDetected(MouseEvent event)
{
    Base item = getTreeCell().getItem();

    Dragboard dragboard = getTreeCell().startDragAndDrop(TransferMode.MOVE);

    //-----get info from the item and put it in the clipboard 

    dragboard.setContent(content);

    //event.consume();
}

@FXML
public void onDragEntered(DragEvent event)
{
    boolean acceptDrag = false;

    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();

    Base current = getTreeCell().getItem();

    //-----get the info from the clipboard and do something with it
    //-----essentially the acceptDrag will be set to true here

    if((_isDragAccepted = acceptDrag))
    {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        //event.consume();
    }
}

@FXML
public void onDragOver(DragEvent event)
{
    if(_isDragAccepted)
    {
        event.acceptTransferModes(TransferMode.MOVE);
        //event.consume();
    }
}

@FXML
public void onDragExited(DragEvent event)
{
    _isDragAccepted = false;

    //event.consume();
}

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@FXML
public void onDragDropped(DragEvent event)
{
    Dragboard dragboard = event.getDragboard();

    TreeItem<Base> currentItem = getTreeCell().getTreeItem();

    Base current = getTreeCell().getItem();

    //-----get info from clipboard again and do the necessary stuff
    //-----essentially an item will be transfered here from one node to another

    event.setDropCompleted(true);

    //event.consume();
}
```

I also got some information about the event handling in javafx from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/events/jfxpub-events.htm) link

According to this if the event was not consumed, it should bubble up all the way to the source again, hence it should also pass the TreeView should it not ? So I would really like to know what I am doing wrong here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok So I figured out what the problem was,

I was listening to the wrong event, the event I needed to register was the onDragOver event instead of the onMouseDragged event.

So in case anyone ever needs an autoscrollTreeView, the final solution for an autoscroll treeView looks like this now:

```
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.LongProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleDoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleLongProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.input.DragEvent;

import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow;

@SuppressWarnings("restriction")
public class AutoscrollTreeView<T> extends TreeView<T>
{
    // region Enumerations

    private enum ScrollDirection
    {
        None, Top, Bottom
    }

    // endregion

    // region Static

    private static final double _milliSecondToSecondFactor = 1.0d / 1000.0d;

    // endregion

    // region Fields

    /**
     * the time interval in milliseconds in which the scroll is performed
     */
    private final LongProperty _checkInterval = new SimpleLongProperty(50);
    /**
     * the actual scroll speed when being in the scroll areas
     */
    private final DoubleProperty _scrollSpeed = new SimpleDoubleProperty(1.0);
    /**
     * the scroll speed increment per second the user remain in the scroll area
     */
    private final DoubleProperty _scrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond = new SimpleDoubleProperty(0.0);
    /**
     * distance from the top, which defines the area which will start a scroll in the -y axis
     */
    private final DoubleProperty _dragIdentifierTop = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    /**
     * distance from the bottom, which defines the area which will start a scroll in the +y axis
     */
    private final DoubleProperty _dragIdentifierBottom = new SimpleDoubleProperty();
    /**
     * time at which the user entered the any scroll area
     */
    private long _initialDragTime = -1;
    /**
     * last time the interval was checked
     */
    private long _lastCheck = -1;

    // endregion

    // region Constructor

    public AutoscrollTreeView()
    {
        super();

        addEventHandlers();
    }

    public AutoscrollTreeView(TreeItem<T> root)
    {
        super(root);

        addEventHandlers();
    }

    // endregion

    // region Getter/Setter

    public final void setCheckInterval(long value)
    {
        _checkInterval.set(value);
    }

    public final long getCheckInterval()
    {
        return _checkInterval.get();
    }

    public final LongProperty checkIntervalProperty()
    {
        return _checkInterval;
    }

    public final void setScrollSpeed(double value)
    {
        _scrollSpeed.set(value);
    }

    public final double getScrollSpeed()
    {
        return _scrollSpeed.get();
    }

    public final DoubleProperty scrollSpeedProperty()
    {
        return _scrollSpeed;
    }

    public final void setScrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond(double value)
    {
        _scrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond.set(value);
    }

    public final double getScrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond()
    {
        return _scrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond.get();
    }

    public final DoubleProperty scrollSpeedIncrementPerSecondProperty()
    {
        return _scrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond;
    }

    public final void setDragIdentiferTop(double value)
    {
        _dragIdentifierTop.set(value);
    }

    public final double getDragIdentifierTop()
    {
        return _dragIdentifierTop.get();
    }

    public final DoubleProperty dragIdentifierTopProperty()
    {
        return _dragIdentifierTop;
    }

    public final void setDragIdentiferBottom(double value)
    {
        _dragIdentifierBottom.set(value);
    }

    public final double getDragIdentifierBottom()
    {
        return _dragIdentifierBottom.get();
    }

    public final DoubleProperty dragIdentifierBottomProperty()
    {
        return _dragIdentifierBottom;
    }

    // endregion

    // region Events

    private void onDragEvent(DragEvent event)
    {
        // -----only apply when there is a drag event in progress
        if(event.getEventType().equals(DragEvent.DRAG_OVER))
        {
            if(_lastCheck == -1 || System.currentTimeMillis() - _lastCheck > _checkInterval.get())
            {
                ScrollDirection direction = ScrollDirection.None;
                if(event.getY() <= _dragIdentifierTop.get())
                    direction = ScrollDirection.Top;
                else if(event.getY() >= getHeight() - _dragIdentifierBottom.get())
                    direction = ScrollDirection.Bottom;

                if(direction != ScrollDirection.None)
                {
                    double additionalScrollSpeed = 0;
                    if(_initialDragTime > 0)
                        additionalScrollSpeed = _scrollSpeedIncrementPerSecond.get() * (System.currentTimeMillis() - _initialDragTime) * _milliSecondToSecondFactor;
                    else
                        _initialDragTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

                    if(direction == ScrollDirection.Bottom)
                        scrollY(_scrollSpeed.get() + additionalScrollSpeed);
                    else
                        scrollY(-(_scrollSpeed.get() + additionalScrollSpeed));
                }
                else
                {
                    _initialDragTime = -1;
                }   

                _lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
            }
        }
        else
        {
            _initialDragTime = -1;
            _lastCheck = -1;
        }
    }

    // endregion

    // region Private

    /**
     * adds the necessary event filters
     */
    private void addEventHandlers()
    {
        addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_OVER, event -> onDragEvent(event));
        addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_EXITED, event -> onDragEvent(event));
        addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_DROPPED, event -> onDragEvent(event));
        addEventHandler(DragEvent.DRAG_DONE, event -> onDragEvent(event));
    }

    private void scrollY(double offset)
    {
        VirtualFlow<?> flow = ((VirtualFlow<?>) lookup("VirtualFlow"));
        flow.adjustPixels(offset);
    }

    // endregion
}
```

Comment: Great post, thanks for this, was having trouble trying to solve this issue. I did encounter a slight bug however, with  if(event.getY() >= getHeight() - _dragIdentifierBottom.get()), it was never reading a bottom scroll, only the top, after I removed this check and simply used an else statement it worked fine. Unsure of reason, could even be somewhere else in my code, but thanks again !!